# Multiple pages into single page pdf-lib node js

Tags: node.js, pdf

I am creating a node.js application and I want to combine multiple pages into single page from pdf and which creates a new final output pdf file. I am using [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) for node js.

How to achieve to solution with this [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) or is there anyother libs which can help?

Example: ABC.pdf containing 16 pages then I need output file XYZ.pdf which has 4 pages and each page contains 4 pages from ABC.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with coherentpdf.js:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/coherentpdf

You would use the function "fromFile" to load the file, the function "impose" to build the new PDFs, and the function "toFile" to write the file back out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this lib is really great.
I checked and tried twoUp(pdf) but it is combining only two pages per page I need 4 pages into single page. can you please help for that with this lib?

Comment: Yes, you use the "impose" function as I suggested... twoUp and twoUpStack are old functions from before impose existed...

Comment: I am not able to impose pdf as per my requirement can you please help with example for the same?

Comment: Well, please show me what call to impose you made, and I can look at it. If you can supply the file, that would help too.

Comment: `var pdf = coherentpdf.fromFile('./pdfs/out.pdf', '')`
`var imposed = coherentpdf.impose(pdf, 122, 2, true, true, true, true, 100, 1000, 10);`
`coherentpdf.toFile(imposed, './pdfs/out2.pdf', false, false);`

Comment: You have set 'fit' to true. This means the X and Y numbers are the width and height of the new page. 122x2 pts is a tiny tiny page. Also your spacing is enormous at 1000. Read through the parameters again carefully and choose more sensible numbers.

Comment: I am not able to understand can you please help me your help will be much appreciated, I have a pdf file with A4 pages size with total pages 16, I want output pdf file with 4 pages and each page containing 4 pages with equivalent size.

Comment: So where are you getting the numbers 122,2,10,1000, and 10 from?

Comment: That I entered randomly because I am not able to understand the syntax clearly